# Dispaly time in a dialog box response

Tags: bash, dialog

I am having issue getting a dialog box to display time. 
I am using 
date +"%T" as the means to show the time but when I use it in a message dialog it just shows it verbose as date +"%T" rather then 07:41:40 I have tried assigning the value to a variable and calling it in the dialog box script but still I can not get it to work. I am wondering if my response dialog box needs to be a different format or if my parentheses usage is screwy. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

dialog --title "Message"  --yesno "Do you want to see the system time?" 6 25

z="date +"%T""
if [ "$?" != "1" ]
then
  dialog --title "message"  --msgbox "$z" 6 25
else
  dialog --title "Message"  --msgbox "ok soo what" 6 25 
fi
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `z="date +"%T""` by `z=$(date +"%T")`.

Comment: Ok I got that part fixed and I can now get the date as a response but it seems no matter which selection is made I get the date. In a yesno dialog box yes is supposed to give you a "0" and no is supposed to give you a "1" but I does not seem what I hit in the box the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

dialog --title "Message"  --yesno "Do you want to see the system time?" 6 25

if [ "$?" != "1" ]
then
  z=$(date +"%T")
  dialog --title "message" --msgbox "$z" 6 25
else
  dialog --title "Message" --msgbox "ok soo what" 6 25 
fi
```

`$?` contains the return code of the previous command.

Comment: So dont declare the variable till after the "if" statement.